# PHPMailer error - SMTP Error: Data not accepted

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

I have done a contact form and obviously I would like to receive a confirmation email when a user fill out this form on my website.

I'm using PHPMailer. When I test the code on my computer as localhost, everything works fine and confirmation message is received properly.

Here you are the PHP script:

```
<?php

$Name= $_POST['Name'];
$Email = $_POST['Email'];
$Message = $_POST['Message'];

if ($Name=='' || $Email=='' || $Message==''){

echo "<script>alert('Please fill out mandatory fields');location.href ='javascript:history.back()';</script>";

}else{

require("archivosformulario/class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->From     = $Email;
$mail->FromName = $Name; 
$mail->AddAddress("myemail@gmail.com");


$mail->WordWrap = 50; 
$mail->IsHTML(true);     
$mail->Subject  =  "Contact Form";
$mail->Body     =  "Name: $name \n<br />".    
"Email: $Email \n<br />".    
"Message: $Message\n<br />";


// SMTP Server

$mail->IsSMTP(); 
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;    
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl"; 
$mail->Username = "myemail@gmail.com"; 
$mail->Password = "mypassword"; 

if ($mail->Send())
echo "<script>alert('We have received your message. We will contact you shortly.');location.href ='javascript:history.back()';</script>";
else
echo "<script>alert('Error');location.href ='javascript:history.back()';</script>";

}

?>
```

The problem is when I upload this PHP script on a web hosting (i.e 123-reg.co.uk), it doesn´t work.

Error message:

```
SMTP Error: Data not accepted
```

Here you are the PHP script:

```
<?php

$Name= $_POST['Name'];
$Email = $_POST['Email'];
$Message = $_POST['Message'];

if ($Name=='' || $Email=='' || $Message==''){

echo "<script>alert('Please fill out mandatory fields');location.href ='javascript:history.back()';</script>";

}else{

require("archivosformulario/class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->From     = $Email;
$mail->FromName = $Name; 
$mail->AddAddress("email@mydomainat123-reg.com");


$mail->WordWrap = 50; 
$mail->IsHTML(true);     
$mail->Subject  =  "Contact Form";
$mail->Body     =  "Name: $name \n<br />".    
"Email: $Email \n<br />".    
"Message: $Message\n<br />";


// SMTP Server

$mail->IsSMTP(); 
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;    
$mail->Host = "smtp.123-reg.co.uk";
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
$mail->Port = 25;
$mail->Username = "email@mydomainat123-reg.com"; 
$mail->Password = "password"; 

if ($mail->Send())
echo "<script>alert('We have received your message. We will contact you shortly.');location.href ='javascript:history.back()';</script>";
else
echo "<script>alert('Error');location.href ='javascript:history.back()';</script>";

}

?>
```

I have tried uploading and executing this PHP script from another free web hosting but it was to not avail.

I'm kind of new in PHP, especially in dealing with mail functions.

What can be the reason? Any additional help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You are using an old version of PHPMailer and have based your code on an obsolete example. [Get the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). You have shown two bits of code that do the same thing - I assume the second is the right one. You need to show the debug output you see with SMTPDebug = 2. If you're using 123-reg, I pity you.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Synchro. I'm using PHPMailer 5.2.4 which I think is the latest version of PHPMailler.

Do you recommend me another web hosting? Which one?

Comment: No, 5.2.4 is years out of date. It would have been faster for you to just click the link I gave you rather than typing that comment. I'd recommend gandi.net for hosting; not as cheap as 123, but they actually do their job properly.

Answer (score 5):

Your server doesn't allow different sender and username you should config: `$mail->From` like `$mail->Username`

Moreover...

Most times I've seen this message the email gets successfully sent anyway, but not always. To debug, set:

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = true;
```

You can either echo the debug messages or log them using `error_log()`:

```
// 'echo' or 'error_log'
$mail->Debugoutput = 'echo';
```

A likely candidate especially on a heavily loaded server are the SMTP timeouts:

```
// default is 10
$mail->Timeout = 60;
```

`class.smtp.php` also has a Timelimit property used for reads from the server!

Hope this information helps! :)

Comment: Apart from your first assertion (which may not be true for 123), all of these are wrong or ineffective. `SMTPDebug` is a numeric value, and you won't see server responses unless you set it to 2. `Debugoutput` defaults to 'echo' anyway. The default `Timeout` is 300, not 10.

Comment: Here you are the debug output:

`SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP gg7sm19589714wjd.10 gsmtp

SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service [IP]  250- SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN  XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOATUH 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-PIPELINING 250-CHUNKING 250 SMTPUTF8

gsmtp

SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 2.1.5 Flushed gg7sm19589714wjd.10 - gsmtp

SMTP Error: Could not authenticate`

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems "Username and Password not accepted" Can you log into your account manually?

Comment: You have to allow less secure apps to log in here https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps.